# Segfault when setting a GtkSharp ComboBox with a System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, timer, gtk, gtk#

I'm having a little bit of a problem with the `Timer` object in `System.Timers`, and using it to set the options of a ComboBox in the C# bindings for GTK; I'm getting segfaults, and I think it's due to the fact that when `Timer` invokes one of it's attached `Elapsed` callbacks, it executes in a thread pool.  Here is some sample code of the problem:

`combobox1` is a Gtk ComboBox added using the GUI designer in MonoDevelop, `MainWindow.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    List<string> cbOptions = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
        : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
        combobox1.Sensitive = false;
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    public void SetOptions(List<string> options, string initial)
    {
        // Clear & repopulate
        if (options?.Count > 0)
        {
            // Clear
            for (int i = 0; i < cbOptions.Count; i++)
                combobox1.RemoveText(0);

            // Set
            foreach (string opt in options)
                combobox1.AppendText(opt);

            // Set the default
            combobox1.Active = options.IndexOf(initial);
            combobox1.Sensitive = true;
            cbOptions = options;
        }   
        else
            combobox1.Sensitive = false;
    }   
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Gtk;

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static MainWindow win;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();
            win = new MainWindow();
            win.Show();

            Timer t = new Timer(2000.0);
            t.Elapsed += SetCB;
            t.Start();

            Application.Run();
        }

        public static void SetCB(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            List<string> options = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
                options.Add(string.Format("{0} 000 000 000", i));

            Random r = new Random();
            win.SetOptions(options, string.Format("{0} 000 000 000", r.Next(1, 25)));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some sort of GUI thread I can ensure that the callback is running on so I don't get this issue?  If you remove the `Timer` code and add a call to `SetCB(null, null);` before `Application.Run();`  You'll see this perform as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. If you're messing around with multiple threads, you need to encase encase your GTK GUI calls in a delegate, and pass that to `Gtk.Application.Invoke()`.

e.g.

```
Gtk.Application.Invoke(delegate {
    comboBox1.AppendText("Option X");
});
```

This is the safe & correct way to do it.

Comment: yes, and that's exactly where gui-thread-check would have helped

Answer (score 1):

A segfault is either a Mono bug, or the result of using threads incorrectly in GTK. Please use this little tool to try to determine if it's the latter or not: https://github.com/slluis/gui-thread-check

Comment: Neat tool.  I'll try it out sometime.  I figured out what the real solution is and posted an Answer.